# Iphone changing to another view [BEGINNER]

Tags: iphone

Hi I have a small doubt, I have 3 Nib Files:

1. ConfigureContacts.xib
2. CallContactsViewController.xib
3. MainWindow.xib

When Application starts I do:

```
[window addSubview:callContactsViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

So that the CallContactsViewController.xib is loaded.

Inside CallContactsViewController.xib there is a button, that when presses jumps to:

```
-(IBAction)configureContacts:(id)sender
{
    configureContacts = [[ConfigureContacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfigureContacts" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:configureContacts.view];   

}
```

The idea is that when the button is pressed it goes to the "next window" which is the other .xib file. Is this the correct way of changing through xibs ? Am I wasting memory here ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

is ConfigureContacts a ViewController subclass? (It looks like it is)

if so you would actually do something like this

```
-(IBAction)configureContacts:(id)sender
{
    configureContacts = [[ConfigureContacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfigureContacts" bundle:nil];

    [self pushviewController:configureContacts animated:YES];
}
```

My Guess this is what you want to do.

[self.view addSubview:configureContacts.view] should work as well however it will change only part of the view and keep you on the same 'Window' so to speak.

Comment: Yes ConfigureContacts is a ViewController subclass.
Using pushviewController yields a warning, CallContactsViewController may not respond to -pushViewController.
It generates when runned an EXCEPTION:

[CallContactsViewController pushviewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd1b2a0

Answer (score 0):

pushViewController is a method from UINavigationController, which is used for managing hierarchical viewControllers. It sounds like that might be what you're trying to do here, in which case adding a UINavigationController to your code might be the way to go.

Alternatively, you could implement a third UIViewController that owns both CallContrats and ConfigureContacts and is responsible for switching between them.

Check out the [sample code](http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4443) from Beginning iPhone Development 3. Specifically, check out the programs "06 View Switcher" and "09 Nav". I think they'll have the code that you're looking for.